# Set File Extension in CakeResponse

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm trying to generate a CSV file on the fly, depending on what the user selects as report output. Retrieving the data and writing it to a file using CakeResponse is done, however I'm struggling to set the file extension to '.csv', the file get downloaded as a normal text file.
CakePHP documentation suggests I do this:

```
$this->response->type('csv');
```

..but even this is not working, I'm still getting a text file. Can anyone shed some light? Please note, I'm not looking for new methods to generate a CSV file, I just want to change the extension. Thank you.

This is how I download the file:

```
$this->response->body($this->constructFileBody($logs));

    return $this->response;
```

This is the method 'constructFileBody', although I think its beyond the scope of this question:

```
public function constructFileBody($logs = array()){

    $content = "";
    for($i = 0; $i < count($logs); $i++){

        $row = $logs[$i]['EventLog'];
        $line = $row['description'] . "," . $row['user'] . "," .  $row['affected_user'] . "," . $row['report_title'] . "," . $row['date_created'] . "\n";

        $content = $content . $line;
    }

    return $content;

}
```

Comment: show the code what method you have tried to download the file

Comment: I've added the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i saw your code, I don't think you used the header anywhere, try this code:

```
//create a file
$filename = "export_".date("Y.m.d").".csv";
$csv_file = fopen('php://output', 'w');

header('Content-type: application/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');

$results = $this->ModelName->query($sql);   // This is your sql query to pull that data you need exported
//or
$results = $this->ModelName->find('all', array());

// The column headings of your .csv file
$header_row = array("ID", "Received", "Status", "Content", "Name", "Email", "Source", "Created");//columns you want in csv file
fputcsv($csv_file,$header_row,',','"');  

// Each iteration of this while loop will be a row in your .csv file where each field corresponds to the heading of the column
foreach($results as $result)
{
// Array indexes correspond to the field names in your db table(s)
$row = array(
    $result['ModelName']['id'],
    $result['ModelName']['received'],
    $result['ModelName']['status'],
    $result['ModelName']['content'],
    $result['ModelName']['name'],
    $result['ModelName']['email'],
    $result['ModelName']['source'],
    $result['ModelName']['created']
);

fputcsv($csv_file,$row,',','"');
}

fclose($csv_file);
```

Now look at your code and get the line of code mine which needs to be replaced.

Comment: Although you gave a bit too much ;), I used the two header lines and it worked!! Thank you!

Comment: It might work, but issuing headers from a controller action (I assume it's a controller action) isn't the right way to do things. For one it makes untestable code.